# Searching a dictionary in scipy weave

Tags: c++, python, optimization, data-structures, scipy

I am working on a project to optimize an algorithm that contains a huge for-loop but has to be called in Python so I am using the scipy weave tool. One of the lines of code I have is in Python:

```py
if entry not in a_set:
    #do something
```

I want to continue to have constant look-up time like a set, so I was going to use a dictionary in order to speed up the look up time. I need to perform the same functionality in my C++ code. I have to pass the set in as an argument.

1. Is the only way to do this with a dict (`py::dict`)? And if so how do I call the containskey(key) function in the inline C code? Do I need to use a call to python to have that functionality?
2. Is there another way/data structure that I could use as specified by the scipy weave?

The reference I am basing it off of is: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/weave/doc/tutorial.txt

Comment: I doubt you can improve on python's "if key not in dict", but if you wanted to stay in c++ instead of breaking your code into multiple functions you could try: 
PyObject* item = NULL;
item = PyDict_GetItem(mydict.ptr(),item);
Then handle the response based on the value of item (return item != NULL).
I would strongly suggest you keep python O(1) lookups in python if you can.